# Saving int Unicode codepoint to UTF-8 file

Tags: c, utf-8, io

### Context

Debian 64bits
Trying to write a int, eg 233 to a file and make it text print "é".

### Question

I cannot understand how i could write a utf8 equivalent char, eg "é" or any UTF-8 char largely wider than a char type can contain. The file should be human readable to send it over the network.

My goal is to write an int to a file and get its utf8 equivalent.

I don't know what I am doing.

### Code

```
FILE * dd = fopen("/myfile.txt","w");
fprintf(dd, "%s", 233); /* The file should print "é" */
fclose(dd);
```

Thanks

UPDATE :

According to Biffen comment, here is another pices of code which writes "E9" (the hexadecimal value of "é");

```
int p = 233;
char r[5];
sprintf(r,"%x",p);
printf("%s\n",r);
fwrite(r,1,strlen(r),dd);
fclose(dd);
```

How to convert it to "é" ?

## Update final working code :

```
UFILE * dd = u_fopen("/myfile.txt","wb", NULL, NULL);
UChar32 c = 233;
u_fputc(c,dd);
u_fclose(dd);
```

Comment: The character `é` takes two UTF-8 units to encode (0xC3, 0xA9). Why not just use a string literal with an [escape sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape), e.g. `"\u00E9"`?

Comment: ...and the `fprintf()` won't work since `%s` expects a char *pointer*, and it's unlikely that what you want to print is at memory address 233. Do you enable compiler warnings?

Comment: I updated the question to make it clearer than in a comment. Now, I get the E9 thing but how to write it to file to get "é" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>The standard library has [`codecvt`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt) for encoding conversions, but as far as I remember GCC, for one, still doesn't have a full implementation.</del> **Edit:** Missed the [c](/questions/tagged/c) tag. `codecvt` is C++.

The ‘algorithm’ for converting a Unicode codepoint to a sequence of UTF-8 units is not too complex, so you could implement it yourself fairly easily.  [Here](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=iws-appendixa)'s a page describing the procedure, and [here](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html)'s an other good resource.

But if you know you'll be doing a lot of Unicode-related stuff, I'd recommend using a library. [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org) is a popular choice.

Comment: Accepted because I will use ICU. Thanks !

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Ooops, my bad.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to expect `printf()` to know about UTF-8, which it doesn't.

You can implement UTF-8 encoding yourself, it's a very simple encoding after all.

A solution might look like this:

```
void put_utf8(FILE *f, uint32_t codepoint)
{
    if (codepoint <= 0x7f) {
       fprintf(f, "%c", (char) codepoint & 0x7f);
    }
    else if (codepoint <= 0x7ff) {
       fprintf(f, "%c%c", (char) (0xc0 | (codepoint >> 6)),
                          (char) (0x80 | (codepoint & 0x3f));
    }
    else if (codepoint <= 0xffff) {
       fprintf(f, "%c%c%c", (char) (0xe0 | (codepoint >> 12)),
                            (char) (0x80 | ((codepoint >> 6) & 0x3f),
                            (char) (0x80 | (codepoint & 0x3f));
    }
    else if (codepoint <= 0x1fffff) {
       fprintf(f, "%c%c%c%c", (char) (0xf0 | (codepoint >> 18)),
                              (char) (0x80 | ((codepoint >> 12) & 0x3f),
                              (char) (0x80 | ((codepoint >> 6) & 0x3f),
                              (char) (0x80 | (codepoint & 0x3f));
    }
    else {
        // invalid codepoint
    }
}
```

You'd use this like so:

```
FILE *f = fopen("mytext.txt", "wb");
put_utf8(f, 233);
fclose(f);
```

and it will then output the two characters 0xC3 and 0xA9 to `f`.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) for more details on UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void){
    wchar_t utfchar = 233;
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    wprintf(L"%lc\n", utfchar);
}
```

You only need to find the corresponding `fprintf` to print to a file.

Comment: I would like to avoid the wide chars if possible and stick to utf8

Comment: Will this really print the two bytes 0xC3 and 0xA9, though?

Comment: @Biffen (Replying to myself.) Tested it and it seems it does.

Comment: I _think_ this only works if you're in a UTF-8 locale. Otherwise you're likely to get ISO-8859-1 (or similar single-byte encoding).

Answer (score 1):

You could install the  `libunistring-dev` package for [GNU libunistring](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libunistring/), then include `<unistr.h>` and use e.g. `u32_to_u8` function to convert an UCS-4 string to an UTF-8 string. See [libunistring documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/manual/html_node/index.html#Top). Perhaps use [`<unistdio.h>`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/manual/html_node/unistdio_002eh.html#unistdio_002eh)